# Heatmap from List

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list `x` which contains intensities in the range 0 to 1. I want to create a heatmap with a squared grid.

For example:

```
x = [0, 0.1, 0, 0.5, ..., 0.5]
n = len(x)    
dim = math.sqrt(n) + 1
```

But how can I create an array with `dim × dim` (the not available last values could be zero) and create the heatmap in a specified size (for example 1024×769)?

Comment: This is a formidable task for numpy. create a 1-dimensional numpy array of size n*n, then fill in the values from your list. Afterwards use `reshape` to resize it to the dimensions you want.

Comment: numpy doesn't [scare](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/formidable) easily.

Comment: @jedwards, ooops - translation bug - although it is very surprising that they managed to get the meaning so different from the french one :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you could use numpy, and plot with the help of seaborn:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x_list = np.random.rand(100).tolist()
x = np.array((x_list))
# x_res=x.reshape(math.sqrt(len(x)),math.sqrt(len(x))) #old
x_res=x.reshape(int(math.sqrt(len(x))),int(math.sqrt(len(x))))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
sns.heatmap(x_res, square=True, ax=ax)
plt.yticks(rotation=0,fontsize=16);
plt.xticks(fontsize=12);
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('colorlist.png')
```

Which produces[image: result]

Comment: For those who get `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` replace `x_res=x.reshape(math.sqrt(len(x)),math.sqrt(len(x)))` with `x_res=x.reshape(int(math.sqrt(len(x))),int(math.sqrt(len(x))))`

Comment: Just changed it in 2021 based on @divaypandey comment. Started to receive downvotes and could not get why :D. Should work now. Thank you.